# Impossible to update and upgrade Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: linux, debian, raspbian

I am working with a Raspberry Pi 3 and I got a problem with these commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I got this output for the error :

```
W: Failed to fetch
http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/InRelease 
Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release
file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/InRelease  Unable to
find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file
(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease  Unable
to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file
(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

I looked at other forums but it didn't solve my problem, this one for example : https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2153680.html

This is my sources list (/etc/apt/sources.list) :

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib    non-free rpi 

deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi 

deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

So, I don't know where exactly comes from my problem, maybe it's a problem of architecture.

Comment: I fixed text including `http:` string for you to avoid confusion. Please check if I did it right.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is clearly because apt-get is trying to get amd64 packages which don't exist for the RPi (the RPi has an arm7hf architecture). You said you looked at other forums, but did you actually execute some of the troubleshooting steps from those forums? The one you've linked to deals with amd64, so if you did any of those steps you might have created an issue somewhere.

Also, I just noticed that the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` have issues, the correct content should be:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi

deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

Note the "http://" prefix which was incorrectly spelled in your pasted example. Can you retry with these fixes?

Comment: I *think* maybe what happened with the "htp" thing (notice the first error doesn't match the file) is because the OP did not format it correctly and the system rejected it because there's a limit on the number of links you include.  Or, that could really be the error...

Comment: I think I had to change the architecture for installing a package few times ago. How is possible to get back back the right architecture ? The arm7hf one.

The file sources.list is correct, I couldn't post more than two links, that's why I deleted a "t" for http://, the problem doesn't come from there.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have configured a wrong architecture on your RPi. Run `dpkg --print-architecture` to see which architecture you have. What you need is `armhf`:

```
dpkg-architecture -a armhf
```

You may also want to remove unused architectures (like `amd64`) with

```
dpkg --remove-architecture amd64
```

And while you're at it, you may remove AMD64 packages if you don't need them, by running the following command (check the list of packages to be purged before accepting!):

```
apt-get purge .*:amd64
```

Comment: Thanks, now I can update : sudo apt-get update, but the command : sudo apt-get purge .*:amd64 is not working, I got that : E: Unable to locate package .*
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '.*'
Morevover, I got some troubleshooting with the upgrade command (sudo apt-get upgrade) : insserv: warning: script 'influxdb.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides

Comment: That error means you don't have any packages to purge (which is good). Regarding the `insserv` warning, you may just ignore it, or [fix the tags](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) manually.

Comment: dpkg --remove-architecture arm worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Only after removing arm and amd64 architectures was I able to successfully run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Weirdly though `dpkg --print-architecture` did not show arm or amd64.

This was a fresh install of raspberry jessie on an SDCard from Mac OSX.